# how to change only hovered icon Color in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have 3 icons for example and I want to Change the Color of the  hovered one without creating variable for every icon
,** I'm using "Mouse Region" Widget and when I hover an icon  it Hovers another one too ...
here is my Code:

```
 MouseRegion(
     onHover: (event) => {
          setState((){
                   isHover=true;
                    })
                      },
                  onExit: (event)=>{
                   setState((){
                       isHover=false;
                        })
                 },
     child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.instagram,color: isHover ? Color(0xFF54b981) : Colors.white,))),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track hover index with single nullable int. Creating separate widget a good option.

```dart
class SF extends StatefulWidget {
  const SF({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SF> createState() => _SFState();
}

class _SFState extends State<SF> {
  int? hoveredIndex;

  _onExit(_) {
    setState(() {
      hoveredIndex = null;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          MouseRegion(
            onEnter: (event) {
              setState(() {
                hoveredIndex = 0;
              });
            },
            onExit: _onExit,
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.instagram,
              color: hoveredIndex == 0 ? Color(0xFF54b981) : Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          MouseRegion(
            onEnter: (event) {
              setState(() {
                hoveredIndex = 1;
              });
            },
            onExit: _onExit,
            child: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.instagram,
              color: hoveredIndex == 1 ? Color(0xFF54b981) : Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by 2 options

1. Create 3 different variables and save each icons hover state in respective variable
2. Extract this widget to a new stateful widget add all logic in it and use that class..

Option 2 is a good practice to follow.